# Override CSS file from composer installed module

Tags: magento2, overrides, css, third-party-module

I've one composer module which has CSS stored in `view/base/web/css/style.css`

How can I override this file so that I can modify it.

I tried copying that file to my custom theme as below,

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/ChildTheme/Vendor_Module/web/css/style.css
```

But this doesn't work for me. Any ideas ?

**UPDATE**

Actually thing is CSS is responsible for styling order PDF so I think it will not work by putting it at frontend theme. I'm not sure but I've to make admintheme and then override into it

Answer (score 0):

You can add this CSS File as:

```
app/design/frontend/VendorName/ChildTheme/Vendor_Module/web/css/style.css
```

Hope this will Help!!

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right path!

After copying the file in app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/ChildTheme/Vendor_Module/web/css/style.css

You need to know which deploy environment your in, so execute this CLI command in Magento Root directory  php bin/magento deploy:mode:show

If you are in developer mode go to

> back office => system => cache management

, click on button Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache  and clear cache.

If you are in default or production mode generate the static content using the CLI command bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy {local you are testing with default is en_US}

Happy coding

Comment: Haha, Thanks for more clarifications but I did all but still doesnt work for me. Actually thing is CSS is responsible for styling order PDF so I think it will not work by putting it at frontend theme. I'm not sure but I've to make admintheme and then override into it.

Answer (score 0):

everyone here is missing that the original css files were in the view/**base**/web/css folder, and not the view/frontend/web/css folder.

The way to extend anything outside the /frontend/ folder is unfortunately to make a custom module extending the original, as your app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/ChildTheme/Vendor_Module theme folder can only extend things in the /view/frontend space, which is why when you're extending them, you remove that from the path within your custom theme folder

making an adminhtml theme won't help much either as it's under the same restrictions but for the view/adminhtml space